# iPhone app sending data back to webserver

Tags: iphone, barcode, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk, zbar

A little of your time. I have to develop a barcode application which is invoked from a webpage. Now i have written the javascript for calling the app. Once the app finishes reading the barcode, I have to go back to my webpage and the barcode data should get saved in some textbox in the webpage.

My troubles are:
-> When the webpage triggers the app, i send the page to background. Now when the app returns the data back, how do i populate th webpage's textbox object with the content without refreshing the page. (There are other data inside the page and a luser logged in as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
Here goes the page which calls the app..<html>
<head>



<script src="/Users/User_admin/Downloads/appl/src/main/webapp/static/scripts/gtx/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">



$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fill').click(function(){
$('#div2').load('/Users/User_admin/Desktop/scanner/barcodescanner/local html files/dummy.html #url');
});
});


function startMyApp()
{
  document.location = 'scannerApp://';
}

</script>

</head>

<body align="center">

<h3> Product Info </h3>
<br><br><br>
<label> Product Name </label>
<input type="text"/>
<br><br>
<label> Product Category </label>
<input type="text"/>
<br><br>
<label> Serial Number </label> <div id="div2">[]</div>

<input id="launch" type="button" onclick='startMyApp()' value="Launch Application to scan serial number"> </input>

<br>

<input id="fill" type="button" value="Press button to fill the detail"></input>


</body>

</html>
```